# Deciding what method to call at runtime without using interfaces for context (no Java8 features)

Tags: java, design-patterns

The title can easily be misunderstood, but it boils down to that I most likely require a [design-pattern](/questions/tagged/design-pattern) to eliminate redundant code. To make my question as clear as possible I made a code example instead of writing a vague explanation.

---

Basically, I have the following functions:
*`getValue1()`, `getValue2()`, `getValue3()`, `...` , `getValue12()`*

These functions could look as follows *(though all differ slightly from each other and are not editable by means of making them implement an interface for a strategy pattern)*:

```
public int getValue1()
{
    return 1 + 2;
}
```

Next we have a secondary class `myClass` which requires the values returned by the *getValue()* functions. A function from `myClass` would then look as follows *(each differ in the fact that they make use of a different getValue() function)*:

```
public int getMyValues1()
{
    int[] values = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int[i] = getValue1() // NOTE: getValueX() may output differently each time.
    }
}
```

We have arrived at our problem.
If we would make a *getMyValues()* function for each respective *getValue()*, we would have to copy and then paste the same code several times.
This goes against everything OOP languages stand for - that's why I require your help.

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**
I reopened the question, because I didn't have Java 8 supported on the IDE I am to use.

Basically I have the following setup:

```
getValueClass
    getValue1()
    getValue2()
    etc.

myClass
    getMyValues1()
    getMyValues2()
    etc.

implemetingClass
    private myClass mc = new MyClass()
    main()
    getLowestValue(int[] values)
```

And so *main()* could look as follows - if i'd wish to output the lowest value:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ...
    System.out.print(getLowestValue(mc.getMyValues1()));
    ...
}
```

This edit goes to show that a strategy pattern isn't viable, since I have my functions in one class.

Hopefully this clears up any confusion and I really hope you guys can help me solve this issue!

Comment: lookup strategy pattern.

Comment: Link for the lazy: [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)... It is pretty much like [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Comment: Strategy patterns are possible if every getValue() had its own class and could implement a common interface, then I would be able to pass that class as a new object to a getMyValues function, but unfortunately I am forced to keep every getValue() in the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection. I don't recommend doing it this way but there is a time place for this type of thing.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class ReflectiveGetter {
    private final Object theObject;
    private final String methodPattern;
    private final Map<Integer, Method> methodsByIndex = new HashMap<Integer, Method>();

    public ReflectiveGetter(Object theObject, String methodPattern) {
        this.theObject = theObject;
        this.methodPattern = methodPattern;

        String patternToMatch = methodPattern + "\\d+";
        for(Method m : theObject.getClass().getMethods()) {
            String name = m.getName();

            if(name.matches(patternToMatch)) {
                m.setAccessible(true);
                int i = Integer.parseInt(name.substring(methodPattern.length()));
                methodsByIndex.put(i, m);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getValue(int index)
    throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
        Method m = methodsByIndex.get(index);

        if(m != null) {
            return (Integer)m.invoke(theObject);
        }

        throw new NoSuchMethodException(methodPattern + index);
    }
}
```

Usage is:

```
ReflectiveGetter rg = new ReflectiveGetter(theValueObject, "getValue");
System.out.println(rg.getValue(1)); // prints as if theValueObject.getValue1()
```

Reflection is clumsy and you should not use it if you do not know what you are doing or there are more convenient options.

For example, perhaps the value class should be using a Map to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming these methods are public, then in Java 8, you should be able to use a functional interface (in this trivial example it would be a [`java.util.function.IntSupplier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html)) and pass a reference to these methods as a lambda expression.

Something like (compilation not tested):

```
public int[] getMyValues(IntSupplier supplier) {
    int[] values = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int[i] = supplier.getAsInt()
    }
    return values;
}
```

Called using:

```
int[] values = someobject.getMyValues(someobject::getValues1)
```

This is more or less using those methods as strategies without the need to make an actual interface and multiple implementations: the strategy interface is the functional interface itself and the method references generate the implementation.

**EDIT**: if you can't use Java 8, then you can just define your own interface with just 1 method that returns the `int`.  The calling just becomes longer because of the lack of support for method references:

```
int[] values = someobject.getMyValues(new MyIntProducer() { 
    public int getValue() { return someobject.getValues1(); };
}
```

Note that the `someobject` local variable will need to be made final for this to work.

Comment: This is the ideal solution, because I do not have the luxury to make all the `getValue()` functions implement a common interface to be able to produce a strategy pattern. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have since reopened the question, since I found out that Java 8 isn't supported by the IDE that I am to use.

Comment: I elaborated the answer with a similar version without Java 8